# How do I use conditions to combine two columns to make a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that looks something like the one below and I want to combine the two columns to make a new one.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(({
    'A Code': [np.nan, np.nan, 'aa', 'bb'],
    'B Code': ['bb', 'aa', 'bb', np.nan]}))

df

  A Code    B Code
0   NaN       bb
1   NaN       aa
2   aa        bb
3   bb        NaN
```

If one of the columns is empty, I want to fill the new column with the non-null value. And, if there are values in both columns I want to combine them with a comma. So, in the end I would like something like:

```
    Code
0    bb
1    aa
2   aa,bb
3    bb
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `','.join` the non-null elements of each row:

```
res= (df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis=1)
        .to_frame(name='Code'))

print(res)

    Code
0     bb
1     aa
2  aa,bb
3     bb
```

Comment: Can just do `.to_frame(name='Code')` instead of `rename` + `to_frame`